# javascript onclick, onload, onmouseenter -- the basics

Tags: javascript, jquery

One thing that keeps baffling me is how sometimes when I try to assign a jQuery function via an inline attribute (`onclick="bam();"`), there's perhaps only a 50-50 chance that it'll actually fire off.

I know the function is good because if I assign a regular jQuery `.on('click', function(){...})` it works perfectly. After reading and re-reading everything I can find online about this, I'm just as ignorant as ever.

I'm not seeing the patterns that I need to see and it makes me realize I need to find a simple tutorial about this. I don't want to learn JavaScript, I just want to learn about this one key area.

Comment: There is no such thing as "assigning a jquery function inline". When you do `onclick="doSomething()"` that has nothing at all to do with jQuery (and works just fine without jQuery too).

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: I'm assuming when you assign an inline handler, the script is being processed before the HTML element, therefore not knowing about said element, and on *whatever* -- you receive function is undefined.

Comment: Also, just a guess, but the problem is probably due to the fact that onclick (the js-property/html-attribute) can only have a single function, whereas `on('click'` from jQuery uses `addEventListener` internally (which can handle a lot of events on the same object), so I'm guessing somewhere the onclick-property gets overwritten. But still, without more info it's just a guess.

Comment: To build on this, there is **never** a 50/50 chance a function will fire, it either will or won't, it's never random :)

Comment: Generally speaking, defining things in this manor is not advised, but if you must please make sure that the function is defined before the element is parse in the DOM.

Comment: You guys sound like a bunch of pretentious know-it-all's with your cheap shots disguised as "help." I'm asking a simple question, I don't need any lectures: Do you know of a good resource where I can learn about the topic at hand -- it's a yes or no question, it's not an invitation for pseudo-enlightened, condescending remarks masquerading as unsolicited advice.

Comment: If you're asking why the inline attribute approach doesn't work, then post a jsfiddle (jsfiddle.com). If you're asking for a list of resources to help you learn jQuery then read the "About" page (http://stackoverflow.com/about), particularly "don't ask about".

Comment: @user2777052, here's a page you can try: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp).  I know it's not good practice for some people to use W3Schools, but personally I find it useful.  And, for reference, the syntax for inline events is: `<element on[replace this with event]="javascriptcode();">`.  Good luck!

Comment: W3schools, like everyone and their sister hasn't already heard of it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is an error in the event handler that prevents it from "working" you may think it only gets called 50% of the time but it actually gets called 100% and gives unexpected results 50% of the time.

To see if there are errors you can press F12 in Chrome or Firefox with firebug and check the console. To see if the function gets called the first line in the function could be: `console.log("I am called");` whatever happens after that you should at least see that message in the console.

For better design you should never declare what event should be triggered in your html (inline), it should be done in script and here is where jQuery can make you life easier because it's methods will work and behave the same on all browsers.